# What is the best way to find and replace element in immutable set in Scala?

Tags: algorithm, scala, collections, immutability, combinators

I have some immutable set of sets. Each set-element is a set of Ints, these Ints are unique.
For example, I have Set(Set(1,2,3),Set(4,5,6),Set(7)). I need to find an inner Set contains 3, and to replace this Set by updated Set(1,2,3,10) in order to get Set(Set(1,2,3,10),Set(4,5,6),Set(7)).

I do not want to construct some big block of code with recursions, and I wonder if I have opportunity to do it with combinators, maps, functions(not in imperative way, but using high-level abstractions of Scala language)

Comment: What have you tried? This should be done with a simple `map` + `contains` + `+`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
val outerSet = Set(Set(1,2,3),Set(4,5,6),Set(7))
outerSet.map { innerSet =>
  if (innerSet.contains(3)) innerSet + 10
  else innerSet
}
```

?